# regex optional chars

Tags: c#, regex

```
string = myfx("{0}test123", test);
string2 = myfx("actual string");
```

the lines above are just a couple of 10's of lines of text in a text file. i iterate the text file and would like to know if there is a single regular expression that will cover the 2 scenarios shown above.

The target strings are "test123" and "actual string". Is there a way to tell regular expressions not to pull in the "{0}" if it occurs?

Comment: Sorry if this is something obvious, but what is `myfx`? So you want to match the string "test123" and "actual string" .. what's the "{0}" got to do with it?

Comment: So, you're trying to parse a very specific subset of C#? What exactly are the rules for the strings you want to get? How exactly can the lines look like? What have you tried?

Comment: Unless myfx is string.Format in disguise?

Comment: What do you want to capture in `myfx("{0}actual {1}string{2}")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find all text not inside curly brackets, use the regular expression:

```
(?<=^|\})(?<!\{)[^\{\}]+(?<!\})(?=\{|$)
```

Test:

```
Regex filter = new Regex(@"(?<=^|\})(?<!\{)[^\{\}]+(?<!\})(?=\{|$)");
string text = "Blah { Bleh} Blih {Bloh } Bluh";
foreach (Match match in filter.Matches(text))
{
    Console.WriteLine("\"{0}\"", match.Capture[0].Value);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Output:

```
"Blah "
" Blih "
" Bluh"
```

This method still has limitations.  It assumes curly brackets are paired.  While with a lot more work it could be made fool-proof, I'm hoping it suits your case.

Comment: Your regex matches "oops!" in `"Blah { oops! } Bleh {1} Bloh"` despite the fact that it *is* inside curly brackets.

Comment: If you can assume braces are always correctly paired, this is all you need: `[^{}]+(?![^{}]*})`.  But I don't think this is what the OP was asking anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use:

```
string myfx = "{0}test123";
Regex regex = new Regex("(test123|actual string)");
string capturedValue = regex.Match(myfx).Captures[0].Value;
```

Comment: That's a bit too literal Eric, you cannot asume all the tens of lines contain exactly the same text.

Answer (score 0):

*edit: M42 was right the lookarounds weren't working.*

perhaps:

```
string input = "{9}test123";//"regular string"
var pattern = @"(?>\{\d\})?(?<target>[^""]+)";
var match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
string result = match.Groups["target"].ToString();
```

Comment: Doesn't match `actual string` because of the space in it.